# Accessing refs in a stateful component doesn't work in React?

Tags: reactjs, meteor-react

I'm currently trying to refactor the simple-todos tutorial for meteor using presentational and container components, but ran into a problem trying to access the refs of an `input` in a functional stateless component. I found out that to access `refs`, you have to wrap the component in a stateful component, which I did with the `input`.

```
// import React ...
import Input from './Input.jsx';

const AppWrapper = (props) => { 
  // ... more lines of code 

  <form className="new-task" onSubmit={props.handleSubmit}>
    <Input />
  </form>
}

import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

This Input should be stateful because it uses class syntax, at least I think.

```
export default class Input extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <input 
        type="text"
        ref="textInput"
        placeholder="Type here to add more todos"
      />
    )   
  }
}
```

I use refs to search for the input's value in the encompassing `AppContainer`.

```
import AppWrapper from '../ui/AppWrapper.js';

handleSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  // find the text field via the React ref
  console.log(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.textInput));
  const text = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.textInput).value.trim();
  ...
}
```

The result of the console.log is `null`, so is my Input component not stateful? Do I need to set a constructor that sets a value for `this.state` to make this component stateful, or should I just give up on using functional stateless components when I need to use `refs`?

Comment: Where is `handleSubmit` defined? The `ref` will only be accessible from within the stateful component.

Comment: You can't use refs like this. You're doing 'this.ref' inside a separate component where textInput doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

> or should I just give up on using functional stateless components when I need to use refs?

Yes. If components need to keep references to the elements they render, they are stateful.

Refs can be set with a "callback" function like so:

```js
export default class Input extends Component {

  render() {
    // the ref is now accessable as this.textInput
    alert(this.textInput.value) 
    return ( 
      <input 
        type="text"
        ref={node => this.textInput = node}
        placeholder="Type here to add more todos" 
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use stateful components when using refs. In your handleSubmit event, you're calling 'this.refs' when the field is in a separate component.

To use refs, you add a ref to where you render AppWrapper, and AppWrapper itself must be stateful.

Here's an example:

**AppWrapper** - This is your form

```
class AppWrapper extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <form 
        ref={f => this._form = f} 
        onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit}>
        <Input 
          name="textInput" 
          placeholder="Type here to add more todos" />
      </form>
    );
  }
};
```

**Input** - This is a reusable textbox component

```
const Input = (props) => (
  <input 
    type="text"
    name={props.name}
    className="textbox"
    placeholder={props.placeholder}
  />
);
```

**App** - This is the container component

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const text = this._wrapperComponent._form.textInput.value;
    console.log(text);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <AppWrapper 
        handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit} 
        ref={r => this._wrapperComponent = r}
        />
    );
  }
}
```

http://codepen.io/jzmmm/pen/BzAqbk?editors=0011

As you can see, the Input component is stateless, and AppWrapper is stateful. You can now avoid using `ReactDOM.findDOMNode`, and directly access textInput. The input must have a `name` attribute to be referenced.

You could simplify this by moving the `<form>` tag into the App component. This will eliminate one `ref`.